# How Apache Cassandra can listen to multiple interfaces?

Tags: cassandra

I want Cassandra to listen to multiple native transport addresses. According to `conf/cassandra.yaml`, native transport address is same as `rpc_address`.

Is there any option to set multiple `rpc_address` in Cassandra? I tried

```
rpc_interface: ens33
rpc_interface: ens37
```

And

```
rpc_interface: ens33, ens37
```

None of these worked.

Comment: rpc_address: 0.0.0.0 is what I usually use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer. You have to use:

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
```

And set the `broadcast_rpc_address` something other than 0.0.0.0.

See http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

rpc_address and rpc_interface take single values, so you cannot give them multiple values.

I'm not sure why you would want to use multiple addresses.  Cassandra can make as many connections as needed on the single address.

Comment: Think of a usecase where the Cassandra system has two interfaces, and two clients will try to reach theh DB over the two different interfaces.

I have worked with Postgresql in the past where one can specify `listen_addresses = '*'` for listening all available interfaces. I am looking for similar option in Cassandra.

Comment: I don't think Cassandra supports that use case.  The closest I've seen to that is using one IP address for inter-node communication and a different IP for client connections.